# Get URLs of multiple images uploaded via php

Tags: javascript, php, image, file-upload

I have a Image upload form where in a user can upload Images and the after uploading a order no will be generated and the uploaded images will be shown.

My Upload Page has -

```
 <h2>Upload Images here</h2>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
                First Field is Compulsory. Only JPEG,PNG,JPG Type Image Uploaded. Image Size Should Be Less Than 100KB.
                <hr/>
                <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div><br/>

                <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
            </form>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <!-------Including PHP Script here------>
            <?php include "upload.php"; ?>
```

Upload.php -

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image
$target_path = "uploads/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {//loop to get individual element from the array

    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");  //Extensions which are allowed
    $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));//explode file name from dot(.) 
    $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

    $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];//set the target path with a new name of image
    $j = $j + 1;//increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

  if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) //Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
            && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {//if file moved to uploads folder
            echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
        } else {//if file was not moved.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {//if file size and file type was incorrect.
        echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Javascript to let user add more images -

```
var abc = 0; //Declaring and defining global increement variable

$(document).ready(function() {

//To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files"     button below function will be executed
$('#add_more').click(function() {
    $(this).before($("<div/>", {id: 'filediv'}).fadeIn('slow').append(
            $("<input/>", {name: 'file[]', type: 'file', id: 'file'}),        
            $("<br/><br/>")
            ));
});

//following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file   
$('body').on('change', '#file', function(){
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
             abc += 1; //increementing global variable by 1

            var z = abc - 1;
            var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
            $(this).before("<div id='abcd"+ abc +"' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></div>");

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

            $(this).hide();
            $("#abcd"+ abc).append($("<img/>", {id: 'img', src: 'x.png', alt: 'delete'}).click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }));
        }
    });

//To preview image     
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
    $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
};

$('#upload').click(function(e) {
    var name = $(":file").val();
    if (!name)
    {
        alert("First Image Must Be Selected");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
});
```

I have a table in my database which has the following fields -

Id - order_id - img_url

I don't know what loop should I create in my upload.php file to get this working - 
User uploads images, then new order is created and order_id is generated which will then be updated as new entries to the table with the uploaded image urls.

Thanks